# Per-host or per-deployment subsystem configuration in WildFly

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly

I have a number of demo environments that I would like to setup for different groups of customers. These would contain the same deployment apps (WAR's) but requiring different configurations. currently I'm using:

- 3 datasources (accessed by JNDI) per application (so each environment would need different databases)
- some Naming/JNDI simple bindings which would need to be different by environment.
- one activeMQ queue for environment, also identified via JNDI.

Would it be possible, on Wildfly 11, to configure the Naming, Datasources and ActiveMQ subsystems on a non-global manner ? Maybe by either configuring the subsystems on a server, host or deployment level? I don't mind having multiple Server or Hosts definitions with different network ports (8080, 8081, etc...)

I know that I can setup multiple instances of standalone running on the same machine, each with a different configuration file, but I would realy like to use the same Wildfly instance to manage this scenario. Is this at all possible ?

Thank you,

Comment: It's unclear what you are wanting to actually change, so hard to advise. You could have WARs that contain a properties file that differs per WAR that contain the name of the datasource. Is this the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: I would like to have the configuration on the application server, since the naming, activeMQ and datasource subsystems are common, I'm seeking a way to configure those things on a per-application basis instead of on a per-server (hence globally for all apps deployed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using domain mode where you can manage several servers and assign to them different configuration profile https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Domain+Setup